# Vectorize code in MATLAB (avoid for loops)

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have 4 arrays:

```
k      = [5    0    1    2    3    3    4   ] %// array of indexes
logind = [1    0    0    0    0    0    1   ] %// logical array of indexes's activity
mass   = [100  200  300  400  500  600  700 ] %// array of masses
res  %//some data matrix
```

I want to realize the following algorithm:

1. find nonzero indexes of `logind`. For my example: `c = [1 7]`
2. get the corresponding values of `k` and `mass`. `k([1 7]) = [5 4]` and `mass = [100 700]`
3. and finally realize the following:

`logind(1)==1` -> `k(1)==5` so

```
res(5,1) = res(5,1) + mass(1);
```

`logind(7)==1` -> `k(7)==4` so

```
res(4,7) = res(4,7) + mass(7);
```

---

I know I can do it using for loops, but I work with huge arrays so want to avoid this approach.

What I have already tried:

```
arrayfun( @(x) res(k(x), x) + mass(x) )
```

that works perfectly, but returns just this pare of sums, I don't know how to add it to current array.

Comment: `arrayfun` is not vectorization, it's just a wrapper for a loop i.e. a loop with more overhead. If that works for you in terms of speed, then a loop will be fine. In fact a loop should be faster.

Comment: @Dan I didn't know that! Thank you for information. Does it means we have to avoid `arrayfun` whenever its possible? Is just using `for loop` faster that `arayfun`? About using `arrayfun` - I didn't realize it for all my data (because still don't know how to), so I still don't know is it works for me :)

Comment: `arrayfun` is often slower then a `for`-loop. `for`-loops in MATLAB are actaully very fast these days (provided you preallocate) so you should be careful about wasting your time vectorizing prematurely unless you know the `for`-loop solution is too slow for you. `arrayfun` is often a helpful way to write terser code, which is sometimes more readable and since loops aren't that slow in MATLAB these days you often don't need to avoid `arrayfun` whenever possible. However, it's highly unlikely that `arrayfun` will give yo a speed boost over loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = k(logind)
y = find(logind)

res = zeros(max(k),numel(logind));

ind = sub2ind(size(res),x,y)

res(ind) = res(ind) + mass(x)
```

Although since `logind` dictates column of the element to alter and it can never contain the same column, I don't understand why you need the `res(...) +` part? In which case you could just go

```
res(ind) = mass(x)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is much simpler than my solution:) Wonder if we should expect indices in `k` to add up, since there are duplicates in the example data (but not where `logind==1`). But you're also missing a conversion to `logical`s. Oh, and yours *works*. Deleted mine:(

Comment: @AndrasDeak OP states that `logind` is `logical`, I imagine that it's not explicitly created like in the example but rather a result of some logical operation.

Comment: Possible, but from their `arrayfun` approach this is not clear. Anyway, you're probably right.

Comment: @AndrasDeak @Dan Really `logind` consists of ones and zeros, but it's not literally logical - That's my fault. But really it's easy to convert, so you both can miss this line, I get it.

Comment: I needed time to understand your solution and implement it to my task. I use it into for loop, so `logind` and `k` change at every iteration so they add different part to `res` every time. Now I understand, how useful `sub2ind` function is. Thank you!